# Deleting Records in Bulk in Group Edition

Tags: api, group-edition, bulk-delete

It is possible to delete records in bulk on Group Edition?

1) APIs are not enabled
2) We can not write apex class on Group Edition
3) System logs not allowing to execute any script
4) Data loader also need API enable

I was thinking if we have all these restrictions and we have inserted 1000 records on Group Edition and now want to delete them, how is it possible?

Comment: I believe it depends on the object where these 1000 records are located. I know that some standard objects have a link to a Mass Delete option in the **Tools** section on the landing page. But otherwise, I don't think there is a way to do this. How did you *insert* the 1000 records?

Comment: Dataloader.io should support group edition and allow you to delete records associated with custom objects.

Answer (score 4):

I believe the Mass Delete Records option is available to all editions.

Click Your Name | Setup | Data Management | Mass Delete Records.

Comment: It is, but not for custom object. Apologies i should mention that before.

Comment: Add a master detail field to the custom object, and make account object the master.  Relate those 1000 records to an account record.  When you delete that account record, the 1000 child records will be deleted along with it.  You can get rid of the master detail field afterwards.

Comment: This is quite interesting. Let me go with this approach, will keep you posted.

Comment: curious how this went, didn't have a group edition org to test it out.

Answer (score 2):

If its a custom object, it might be an idea to delete the object, causing the records to be deleted. You could then recreate the object.

Comment: Indeed a good idea, but why I've not already done this is because there are too many fields which I need to create again and some of them are dependent picklist. You can understand the pain now. It's my first and very bad exp working with Group edition. Developers should not be assigned a group edition.

Comment: Does GE have access to the Metadata API? Could you download the object definition via that, delete the object and then recreate it using the XML file?

Comment: No we don't have that access and requested same to salesforce support.

Answer (score 1):

Ask salesforce.com support or AE for temporary API access for this operation. They do that for initial migrations into PE.
Then use Data Loader.
Rup

Comment: Andy suggested same :)

Answer (score 0):

I have been successful in the past logging a Case with Salesforce Support stating that I am doing data migration and request that the API be turned on for a short time.  Try that approach.  They will not leave it on and will not repeatedly turn it on for you to support a process - but they will open it up from time to time if you are indeed doing a true data migration or bulk action like this.

You could always use this situation to try and get your client to upgrade to a proper Salesforce edition if they need to do this often.

Comment: Yeah, logged a case and fingers are crossed now :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this free app to mass delete records from the list view.
https://sites.secure.force.com/appexchange/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000003J6KcEAK&tab=r

This app supports Group edition and also it works well for the custom object also.
I hope this app will helps you to solve your issue.